# Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty with UEFI + Software RAID1

Tags: uefi, raid

How to install Ubuntu on UEFI BIOS with Software RAID1?

Should there be 1 partition for EFI and another partition for RAID1 (root+swap) on each drive?

I wonder how it will update one EFI partition to the other if it's not in RAID1 mode?

Will the update-grub-efi command will update both EFI partitions on both drives like the one in legacy BIOS by using only the update-grub2 command?

I'm using Intel Serverboard S1200V3RPL motherboard with Xeon E-1275 V3 processor. The USB installer is recognized as UEFI: USB while the SSD is P0+P1 SSD. I assume the motherboard recognizes the SSD as in legacy BIOS, right?

What is better for ease of use and stability, UEFI or legacy BIOS?

Been googling around but to no luck.

Comment: related: [Can I install ubuntu 14.04 on my RAIDed desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/479379/can-i-install-ubuntu-14-04-on-my-raided-desktop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem a while ago. Wrote down my solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660023/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-with-a-dual-boot-raid-1-partition-on-an-uefi). I would go with the UEFI solution.